# How do I execute build recursively in a composite project?

Tags: gradle, groovy

my `settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'rpf'
includeBuild( 'is' )
includeBuild( 'sec' ) {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module( "com.xenoterracide.rpf:is:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT" ) with project( ":is" )
    }
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.brightsparklabs.gradle.multi-git' version '1.3.0'
}

group 'com.xenoterracide'
version '0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'

multiGitPluginConfig {
    repositoriesDir = new File('.')
    repositories = [
            'entity-api': 'git@bitbucket.org:xenworks/entity-api.git',
            'entity-jpa': 'git@bitbucket.org:xenworks/entity-jpa.git',
            'util': 'git@bitbucket.org:xenworks/util.git',
    ]
}

task build {
    gradle.includedBuild( 'sec' ).task( ':build' ) // sec is not currently a separate repo
}
```

here's the output

```
xeno@Freyja MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/rpf (master)
$ ./gradlew build --info
Initialized native services in: C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\native
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 14968). The daemon log file: C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\daemon\4.4\daemon-14968.out.log
Starting 297th build in daemon [uptime: 3 hrs 34 mins 24.533 secs, performance: 100%, no major garbage collections]
Using 4 worker leases.
Creating new cache for fileHashes, path C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\.gradle\4.4\fileHashes\fileHashes.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@2668d8c
Starting Build
[composite-build] Configuring build: C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\is

> Configure project :is
Evaluating project ':is' using build file 'C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\is\build.gradle'.
Creating new cache for metadata-1.1/results, path C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\metadata-1.1\results.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@449d02e2
Creating new cache for metadata-2.36/module-metadata, path C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-metadata.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@6867a4bc
Creating new cache for metadata-2.36/module-artifacts, path C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-artifacts.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@6867a4bc
Creating new cache for metadata-2.36/module-versions, path C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-versions.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@6867a4bc
Creating new cache for metadata-2.36/module-artifact, path C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-artifact.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@6867a4bc
Applying dependency management to configuration 'api' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'apiElements' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'archives' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'compile' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'compileClasspath' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'compileOnly' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'default' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'implementation' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'runtime' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'runtimeClasspath' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'runtimeElements' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'runtimeOnly' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'spotbugs' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'spotbugsPlugins' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testCompile' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testCompileClasspath' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testCompileOnly' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testImplementation' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testRuntime' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testRuntimeClasspath' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testRuntimeOnly' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'checkstyle' in project 'is'

Registering project :is in composite build. Will substitute for module 'com.xenoterracide.rpf:is'.
Settings evaluated using settings file 'C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'rpf']

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'rpf' using build file 'C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\build.gradle'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.brightsparklabs.gradle.multi-git:com.brightsparklabs.gradle.multi-git.gradle.plugin'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.brightsparklabs.gradle.multi-git:com.brightsparklabs.gradle.multi-git.gradle.plugin'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'gradle.plugin.com.brightsparklabs:gradle-multi-git'.

All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'build' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':build']
Creating new cache for resourceHashesCache, path C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\.gradle\4.4\fileHashes\resourceHashesCache.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@2668d8c
Invalidating in-memory cache of C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\.gradle\4.4\fileHashes\resourceHashesCache.bin
Creating new cache for taskHistory, path C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\.gradle\4.4\taskHistory\taskHistory.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@696f1bef
Creating new cache for outputFiles, path C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\.gradle\buildOutputCleanup\outputFiles.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@780c9a3
:build (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 25,5,main]) started.

> Task :build UP-TO-DATE
Skipping task ':build' as it has no actions.

:build (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 25,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
```

I think I may have gotten it working partially, but it still isn't building sec

I changed the build task to look like this

```
task build {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild( 'is' ).task( ':build' )
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild( 'sec' ).task( ':build' )
}
```

and here's the output, the problem seems obvious, for some reason it thinks it should be `:sec:is` and not just `:is`, but I haven't figured out how to fix that

```
xeno@Freyja MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/rpf (master)
$ ./gradlew build --info
Initialized native services in: C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\native
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 14968). The daemon log file: C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\daemon\4.4\daemon-14968.out.log
Starting 364th build in daemon [uptime: 4 hrs 4 mins 32.226 secs, performance: 99%, no major garbage collections]
Using 4 worker leases.
Creating new cache for fileHashes, path C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\.gradle\4.4\fileHashes\fileHashes.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@42c3b7af
Starting Build
[composite-build] Configuring build: C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\is

> Configure project :is
Evaluating project ':is' using build file 'C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\is\build.gradle'.
Creating new cache for metadata-1.1/results, path C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\metadata-1.1\results.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@664cab31
Creating new cache for metadata-2.36/module-metadata, path C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-metadata.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@19076773
Creating new cache for metadata-2.36/module-artifacts, path C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-artifacts.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@19076773
Creating new cache for metadata-2.36/module-versions, path C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-versions.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@19076773
Creating new cache for metadata-2.36/module-artifact, path C:\Users\xeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-artifact.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@19076773
Applying dependency management to configuration 'api' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'apiElements' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'archives' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'compile' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'compileClasspath' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'compileOnly' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'default' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'implementation' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'runtime' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'runtimeClasspath' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'runtimeElements' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'runtimeOnly' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'spotbugs' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'spotbugsPlugins' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testCompile' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testCompileClasspath' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testCompileOnly' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testImplementation' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testRuntime' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testRuntimeClasspath' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testRuntimeOnly' in project 'is'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'checkstyle' in project 'is'

Registering project :is in composite build. Will substitute for module 'com.xenoterracide.rpf:is'.
Settings evaluated using settings file 'C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'rpf']

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'rpf' using build file 'C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\build.gradle'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.brightsparklabs.gradle.multi-git:com.brightsparklabs.gradle.multi-git.gradle.plugin'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.brightsparklabs.gradle.multi-git:com.brightsparklabs.gradle.multi-git.gradle.plugin'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'gradle.plugin.com.brightsparklabs:gradle-multi-git'.

All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'build' from project :

> Configure project :sec
Evaluating project ':sec' using build file 'C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\sec\build.gradle'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.github.spotbugs:com.github.spotbugs.gradle.plugin'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.github.spotbugs:com.github.spotbugs.gradle.plugin'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs:gradlePlugin'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.ow2.asm:asm'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.ow2.asm:asm-commons'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.ow2.asm:asm-tree'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.ow2.asm:asm-util'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.ow2.asm:asm-xml'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.apache.bcel:bcel'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'net.jcip:jcip-annotations'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'dom4j:dom4j'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'jaxen:jaxen'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'commons-lang:commons-lang'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.google.code.findbugs:jFormatString'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-annotations'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'xml-apis:xml-apis'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'.
Applying dependency management to configuration 'api' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'apiElements' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'archives' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'compile' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'compileClasspath' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'compileOnly' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'default' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'implementation' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'runtime' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'runtimeClasspath' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'runtimeElements' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'runtimeOnly' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'spotbugs' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'spotbugsPlugins' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testCompile' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testCompileClasspath' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testCompileOnly' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testImplementation' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testRuntime' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testRuntimeClasspath' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'testRuntimeOnly' in project 'sec'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'checkstyle' in project 'sec'

Selected primary task ':build' from project :
Creating new cache for annotation-processors, path C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf\sec\.gradle\4.4\fileContent\annotation-processors.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@283dc88a
Resolving global dependency management for project 'sec'
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.xenoterracide:bom'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-parent'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.fasterxml:oss-parent'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-bom'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.apache:apache'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework:spring-framework-bom'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework.data.build:spring-data-build'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-bom'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework:spring-web'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'javax.validation:validation-api'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework:spring-core'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework:spring-context'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'org.springframework:spring-tx'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.xenoterracide:entity-api'.
Found no composite build substitute for module 'com.xenoterracide:entity-jpa'.
Found project 'project :is' as substitute for module 'com.xenoterracide.rpf:is'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':sec:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':sec:detachedConfiguration15'.
   > project :sec:is was not found.
```

here's how I defined that projects dependency's

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.springframework:spring-web'
    compileOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    compileOnly 'org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence'
    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-tx'
    implementation 'com.xenoterracide:entity-api:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.xenoterracide:entity-jpa:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.xenoterracide.rpf:is:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    testRuntimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3'
    testImplementation 'nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier'
}
```

*how do I get gradle to run the build task successfully for its composite builds?*

Comment: @tkruse since it's not so simple to have this "minimal" because it's very nature is complex... here's the source code for a minimal https://bitbucket.org/account/user/xenworks/projects/GCPD

Comment: All I am asking is that you copy the 3 minimal build.gradle files and settings.gradle files from bitbucket to here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not need to declare a dependencySubstitution in this case:

```
includeBuild( 'sec' ) {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module( "com.xenoterracide.rpf:is:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT" ) with project( ":is" )
    }
}
```

Running a minimal example,

```
includeBuild( 'sec' )
```

works fine with classes from :is being correctly resolved for compiling :sec.

Comment: why isn't it needed? the docs suggest that's required if you're simply substituting a module for a local build of it. I suspect it has something to do with my `build.dependsOn... task` which I was adding to ensure tests were working, if I remove those then it's green but no tests (and I'm not actually convinced it's really building either)